# Segmentation fault while dereferencing the pointer in the calling function

Tags: c++, pointers, segmentation-fault

When I run the following code, I get the segmentation error fault and I cannot rectify my mistake.

```
    void test(int *c)
{
    c++;
    *c = 10;
    cout<<*c<<endl;
}

int main()
{
    int a =2;
    int *b = &a;
    test(b);
    cout<<*b;
    return 0;
}
```

I think that b should point to value '2'. But instead it gives an error.

Comment: Also, don't assume headers. We prefer compilable examples.

Comment: what do you think `c++` does?

Comment: @user202729 Thanks for bringing that up!

Comment: @AndersK. Why can't we access this memory, which is stored in c after the increment?

Comment: @ANKURSATYA Why do you think you can? What do you think it points to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what you move the pointer in the `test`? You move it behind the memory of the  variable `a` and reach undefined behavior.

```
  c
  |
+---+---+
| 2 |   |
+---+---+
      |
     ++c
```

Comment: But the cout statement for '*c' still executes and prints the value '10'. How does this happen?

Comment: @ANKURSATYA You don't own this memory, so trying to access it is undefined behavior. Undefined behavior can mean anything, includes printing `10`, loop infinitely, break your computer, delete your important files, etc.

Comment: The scenario maybe be like further. In PC `a` is placed on the stack before the return address from `main`. Then you move the pointer `c` up on the stack, at least this piece of the stack memory is available. Therefore you can write and read it successfully. But most probably you have overwritten the return address from `main` and reached the crash.

Answer (score 2):

With `c++` you are incrementing the value of the pointer and not the value of the integer. It will point to a new location that was not allocated by you, and it will raise the segmentation fault error. The new location may be used by an other program or by the system.....

Comment: Ah. I understand your reasoning and retract my comment.

Comment: @LucaDiLiello What if this memory is free at execution? Can I use it then?

Comment: Yes, but it's pretty compiler specific, and there is no guarantee how it works.

Comment: @ANKUR SATYA if the memory is free there will be no problems, but the behaviour is not predictable at all given the complexity of modern systems.

Answer (score 2):

```
void test(int *c)
{
   c++;
   *c = 10;
```

`*c = 10` is undefined behavior since you are writing into memory that does not belong to you.

Answer (score 0):

In function test , 'c' has address of 'a' say 1000. Now you increment this address say it gets to 1004 ,now this memory address is not allocated by you .

When you try to access memory which was not allocated by you , Segmentation fault occurs .

Now when you try to print *c ,it might print 10 but  it is undefined behavior which can even crash the PC at times.

To get a better idea ,just think about free() when you free() the memory and then access a variable you might still get the value but it is undefined behavior ,anything can happen .